# Using OxyPlot in WindowsForms

Tags: c#, winforms, oxyplot

So far, from what I've seen on the `OxyPlot` documentation, not much is out there.  How do I take x-y points and graph them using OxyPlot?

Here is my attempt at taking two points and graphing them:

```
var dataModel = new PlotModel { Title = "data plot" };

foreach (var pt in dataProfile)
{
    XYData.Text = String.Format("X:{0} Y:{1}", pt.X,pt.Y);
    dataModel.Series.Add(pt.X, pt.Y); //(obviously wrong here)
    this.plot1.Model = dataModel;
}
```

What do I need to change/add to: `dataModel.Series.Add(pt.X, pt.Y);`, so that it adds points? Additionally, how can I plot points over time? (x-y, plotted as time t passes by)

Does anyone know of a good OxyPlot tutorial site (for WinForms), because I cannot find one (apart from the OxyPlot documentation, which is very broad at best).

Comment: You're kidding, right? There are a ton of examples on github: https://github.com/oxyplot/oxyplot/tree/develop/Source/Examples

Comment: @B.K. I kid you not. Look under the Windows Forms examples, there are only two...both of which do not even pertain to what I'm attempting to do. If you can't help, just keep browsing.

Comment: @John: You don't need WinForms versions of all the examples, only the ones showing how to add it to a WinForm.  The data model is the same...

Answer (score 2):

I know you've mentioned `WinForms`, but you must be able to get comfortable with looking at all of the examples and all of the source code, regardless of the UI framework being used. Look up oxyplot in your favorite search engine and you'll find plenty of examples on their GitHub page (or whatever repo service they'll use whenever this answer is being looked at).

Anyways, what you want is a `ScattierSeries` plot.  You then add points to it.  An example:

```
    public static PlotModel ExampleScatterSeriesPlot()
    {
        var plotModel1 = new PlotModel();
        plotModel1.Subtitle = "The scatter points are added to the Points collection.";
        plotModel1.Title = "ScatterSeries";
        var linearAxis1 = new LinearAxis();
        linearAxis1.Position = AxisPosition.Bottom;
        plotModel1.Axes.Add(linearAxis1);
        var linearAxis2 = new LinearAxis();
        plotModel1.Axes.Add(linearAxis2);
        var scatterSeries1 = new ScatterSeries();
        scatterSeries1.Points.Add(new ScatterPoint(0.667469348137951, 0.701595088793707));
        scatterSeries1.Points.Add(new ScatterPoint(7.74765135149828, 5.11139268759237));
        scatterSeries1.Points.Add(new ScatterPoint(7.97490558492714, 8.27308291023275));
        scatterSeries1.Points.Add(new ScatterPoint(1.65958795308116, 7.36130623489679));
        scatterSeries1.Points.Add(new ScatterPoint(2.6021636475819, 5.06004851081411));
        scatterSeries1.Points.Add(new ScatterPoint(2.30273722312541, 3.87140443263175));
        scatterSeries1.Points.Add(new ScatterPoint(2.15980615101746, 0.208108848989061));
        scatterSeries1.ActualPoints.Add(new ScatterPoint(0.667469348137951, 0.701595088793707));
        scatterSeries1.ActualPoints.Add(new ScatterPoint(7.74765135149828, 5.11139268759237));
        scatterSeries1.ActualPoints.Add(new ScatterPoint(7.97490558492714, 8.27308291023275));
        scatterSeries1.ActualPoints.Add(new ScatterPoint(1.65958795308116, 7.36130623489679));
        scatterSeries1.ActualPoints.Add(new ScatterPoint(2.6021636475819, 5.06004851081411));
        scatterSeries1.ActualPoints.Add(new ScatterPoint(2.30273722312541, 3.87140443263175));
        scatterSeries1.ActualPoints.Add(new ScatterPoint(2.15980615101746, 0.208108848989061));
        plotModel1.Series.Add(scatterSeries1);
        return plotModel1;
    }
```

There are a ton of examples under the example browser link I gave you.  The above code was snipped from there. So, research all of the available options.  OxyPlot is very flexible and I've been able to extend on it easily in my recent project.

Comment: Thank you! Your answer happens to be more helpful than the examples I was looking through.

Comment: @John No problem.  If this has answered your question, don't forget to mark it as an answer.

Comment: the link you posted leads to a japanese website with animals as theme

Comment: @t0b4cc0 That's what happens after over five years. They moved to github -- easily discoverable.

Comment: I know that this happens thats why I made the comment so we dont get redirected to a potentially mallicious website. thanks for changing the link

Comment: Found the examples! It's under the source folder (download the source code to find them) Examples/ExampleLibrary.